# How to make content scroll smoothly in fixed div with page scroll

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a fixed top nav that has the menu change as you scroll down the page. When you scroll past a certain y-point the menu will scroll as you scroll down the page to show the second menu which would become sticky. I have implemented a rough version here: http://jsfiddle.net/hSpLQ/

I have two main issues

1) The content does not scroll smoothly. If you scroll quickly you will notice that the content does not move smoothly.

2) I am not sure this is the best way to implement this type of animation/effect. The code is rough, but I am wondering if there is a better/more optimal way to accomplish this.

Thanks

Here is the code for the rough prototype (same as JsFiddle link)

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                height: 2000px;
            }

            .container {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #CCC;
                height: 80px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .content1, .content2 {
                height: 40px;
                margin: 40px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="content1">
                    lots of text
                </div>
                <div class="content2">
                    more text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();
            if (scrollYpos > 200 && scrollYpos < 300) {
                var y = 200-scrollYpos;
                $(".content").css({'position': 'relative', 'top': y});
            }
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot control the users CPU, browser, browser version, even graphics card, etc. there is not much you can do. You could try to use vanilla JavaScript instead of jQuery to improve performance a bit, but its probably not going to help much (it may not change anything depending of if its the render or the script interpreter who is slow).
In my browser, for instance, your example works quite smoothly.
It really depends on your client how it will look, that's just the web. Don't worry too much about it.

Finally there are 2 things I noticed:

1. You don't have to set "position: relative" each a scroll event is received, just set it once in your stylesheet
2. If one scrolls too fast the menu gets stuck in an odd position

Here is the code to fix the above issue although it may not fix the smoothnes problem:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();

    var y;
    if (scrollYpos > 200 && scrollYpos < 300) {
        y = 200 - scrollYpos;
    } else if (scrollYpos > 300) {
        y = -100;
    } else {
        y = 0;
    }

    console.log(y);
    $(".content").css({'top': y});
});
```

If you just want to smooth out the gaps between scrolling intervals a bit, try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollYpos = $(document).scrollTop();

    var y;
    if (scrollYpos > 200 && scrollYpos < 300) {
        y = 200 - scrollYpos;
    } else if (scrollYpos > 300) {
        y = -100;
    } else {
        y = 0;
    }

    var position = parseInt($(".content").css('top'));
    if((scrollYpos < 300 && scrollYpos > 200)
    || (position   < 0   && position   > -100)) {
        $(".content").stop().animate({'top': y}, 50);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits to the javascript. I ended up changing how it works so that it scrolls smoother. Instead of moving the content based on the number of pixels scrolled I make an animation occur at a specific scroll point. I appreciate the help.